# Problem in Finding Prime Numbers between Two numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I have to find all prime numbers between two given numbers(given in ascending order i.e small, large) I made logic such that my program starts from the given least number till the given most numbers and find factors for each number in between, if factors count are 2 i.e 1 and itself(which is a condition for a prime number), hence it is printed as prime. However I am unable to print my desired output.. can't track why(P.S I am 19 years old newbie in Programming)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        int start,end;
        cin>>start,end;
        for(int i=start+1;i<end;++i){
                int count;
                for(int j=1;j<=i;++j){
                        if(i%j==0 || i/2==0)count++;
                }
                if(count==2) cout<<i<<endl;

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Input: `1 10`

Expected Output:

```
2
3 
5 
7 
9
```

Output: (nothing)

Comment: `cin>>start,end;` does not do what you expect: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator What you want is `cin >> start >> end;`

Comment: Also, `count` is uninitialized. And `|| i/2==0` looks wrong

Comment: "can't track why" enable compiler warnings and do read them. For example clang points exactly where your problems are.

Comment: To really track what goes wrong, learning to use a debugger will be a wonderful experience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has several issues.

1. `cin>>start,end;` is not going to read in 2 numbers. You need `cin >> start >> end;`
2. You are not initializing `count` to anything, so you invoke undefined behavior when you do `count++`. You need to do `int count = 0;`

Also, when checking if `n` is prime, you don't need to check for divisibility by `1` or `n` since this is always true.